# Will this "smart pointer" code leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I want to know if this code, from *Accelerated C++* Section 14.1.2, causes a memory leak when `fn` is called:

```
class IntPtr {
public:
  IntPtr (): p(NULL) {};
  IntPtr (int *ip): p(ip) {};
  IntPtr (const IntPtr& other) { p = new int(*other.p); };
  IntPtr& operator= (const IntPtr&);
  ~IntPtr () { delete p; };

private:
  int *p;
}

IntPtr& IntPtr::operator= (const IntPtr& other) {
  if (&other != this) { delete p; p = new int(*other.p); }
  return *this;
}

void fn () {
    IntPtr a;
    a = new int(9);
}
```

Here's what I think happens when the line `a = new int(9)` is reached:

1. `new int(9)` allocates memory for a single `int` (9) in the heap, and returns a pointer to this memory (an `int *`).
2. An `IntPtr` is created using the `int *` obtained above and the appropriate constructor.
3. `IntPtr::operator=` is called, with LHS a and the `IntPtr` created above as RHS. This operation allocates another block of memory for a single int. The address of this new block is stored in `a.p`.

When the last closing brace is reached, `a` is destroyed, and the second block of memory with it. My question is: what by now has happened to the first block? Is it still on the heap, with nothing pointing to it? What's the fate of the `IntPtr` created in action 2?

Comment: Use your debugger, write down the addresses of the the memory blocks, step through the code.

Comment: The `IntPtr` of section 2 is created temporarily. It is destroyed after assignment has been completed. To illustrate what happens, add output to every method of `IntPtr` and you will see this on console.

Comment: The `intPtr` created in step 2 is a temporary, and ceases to exist on completion of the statement `a = new int(9)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could think about "move assignment" which transfers the pointer from RHS to LHS and resets RHS (to 0). For this, you had to change the parameter to `IntPtr &other`, of course. This may help: [`std::unique_ptr::operator = `](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/operator=/).

Comment: I checked on amazon and this book Accelerated C++ is quite dated : (August 24, 2000). It for sure does not include changes since C++11. In more modern books authors will suggest using smart pointers. But maybe this is an excersice on how classes work.

Comment: It looks to me as if assigning an empty `IntPtr`, such as `IntPtr ip; ip = IntPtr();` will dereference `other.p`, which is `NULL`.  If you’re lucky, this will crash the program with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: what by now has happened to the first block? Is it still on the heap, with nothing pointing to it? What's the fate of the IntPtr created in action 2?

you can rewrite this line:

```
a = new int(9);
```

as:

```
a = IntPtr(new int(9));
    ^^^^^^
```

compiler creates during assignment a temporary object which will be used during assignment. Its destructor will be called at the end of the statement (a semicolon at the end of the line).

This code looks OK - no memory leak should happen.

Comment: The code looks OK from a memory leak perspective, but it is lacking in other respects (_i.e._ it is not exception-safe).

Comment: It looks more like an excercise on how classes work.